# unable to retrive data from multiple table using where condtion

Tags: mysql

```
**this is my sql query to retrive data from database**

$sql="select lab_products.*,lab_category.category_name from lab_products,lab_category where lab_id='$lid' AND  lab_products.category_id=lab_category.id  order by lab_products.id desc";
$res=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

**this is my first table name lab_category **

lab_id  
id  
category_name   
status  
added_on
  

**this is my second table name **

id  
category_id 
lab_id  
test_name   
image   
status  
added_on
```

*i want to retrive data using  lab_id . but the table results is not display any results when i use the condition lab_id=$lid here the lid is retrived from session. its works fine when i remove lab_id condtion but the hole data is showing but i want to show only one data where lab_id =session id which is $lid*

Comment: you should read more about `joins` and `relationships between tables`

Answer (score -1):

You miss the JOIN between your tables, try like this:

```
SELECT lp.*, lc.category_name
FROM lab_products AS lp
LEFT JOIN lab_category AS lc ON lp.category_id=lc.id 
WHERE lp.lab_id='$lid' 
ORDER BY lp.id desc
```

Comment: He is not missing the join if he planned for an inner join, there's no difference between declaring the conditions with "ON" or directly within the WHERE clause..  
Also, he states that the join works correctly, only when he tries to filter a specific sessions ID the results are empty

Comment: @SaarLevy Old school syntax ...